# Highcharts Synchronisation of multiple charts with different sizes

Tags: javascript, highcharts, time-series

this example: [Synchronisation of multiple charts](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/snippets/synchronisation-of-multiple-charts/)

use the chartx and charty position of the mouse to detect which data point is hovered. But if u want to sync charts with different sizes... of course it stops working.

the charts are timeseries with the same data length. Is there a way to synchronise relative?

Greetings mok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working as you expecting, because it's not taking current xAxis *focused* value, but actually the pointer position.
However, I found the example on our Highcharts forum, which shows how to draw the crosshair on all charts, basing on current xAxis position instead of pointer one, so it should help you to solve your problem.

Please refer to this topic: https://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/synchronize-line-chart-with-xrange-chart-t39781/?hilit=synchronization&sid=72b63bab7545ef4ba2c4a102ef52cfa5